# Why System.Xml.Serialization output order changes

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

I just picked up XML serialization in C#. In the course of figuring it out, I stumbled upon an oddity and wanted to know why.

If I use the following code,

```
[Serializable, XmlRoot("ThisIsTheRootName")]
public class Person
{
  public string FirstName;
  public string MiddleName;
  public string LastName;
  [XmlText]
  public string Text;
}
```

I get this output when I serialize:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="IBM437"?>
<ThisIsTheRootName xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <FirstName>firstname</FirstName>
  <MiddleName>middlename</MiddleName>
  <LastName>lastname</LastName>This is some text</ThisIsTheRootName>
```

All the elements are in the order I expected.

If I switch to using a property instead of a field, suddenly the order is not what I would expect. Code:

```
[Serializable, XmlRoot("ThisIsTheRootName")]
public class Person
{
  public string FirstName;
  public string MiddleName { get; set; }
  public string LastName;
  [XmlText]
  public string Text;
}
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="IBM437"?>
<ThisIsTheRootName xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <FirstName>firstname</FirstName>
  <LastName>lastname</LastName>This is some text<MiddleName>middlename</MiddleName></ThisIsTheRootName>
```

**Why does the order change?** Should I prefer properties or fields for this? Does it matter?

Using Visual Studio 2010, C#, .NET 4.0 framework on Windows 7 64bit.

Comment: Not answering your actual question but your could force the order using `[XmlElement(Order=1)]` ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because by default `XmlSerializer` serialize your fields first then your properties. However, you can change this behavior with using `XmlElement` attribute and it's `Order` property like this:

```
[Serializable, XmlRoot("ThisIsTheRootName")]
public class Person
{
  [XmlElement(Order = 1)]
  public string FirstName;
  [XmlElement(Order = 2)]
  public string MiddleName { get; set; }
  [XmlElement(Order = 3)]
  public string LastName;
  [XmlText]
  public string Text;
}
```

Also you might want take a look at these questions:

1. [.NET Serialization Ordering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1018490/net-serialization-ordering)
2. [Force XML elements to match the class order when serializing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1394091/force-xml-elements-to-match-the-class-order-when-serializing)
3. [Change the order of elements when serializing XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6455067/xml-serialization-question-order-of-elementsc)